# Error message: uninitialized constant Rails::Initializer::MemCache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I've installed just about every library/gem that I could find for memcached/memcache, but everytime I attempt to run my application I get this error:

```
Error message:
uninitialized constant Rails::Initializer::MemCache

Exception class:
NameError
```

I have tried $ telnet localhost 11211 and memcached is definitely running. Any ideas?

(I'm running Apache2/Passenger)

Comment: I should also add that I'm using Ruby, not Ruby EE if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up having to put

```
require 'MemCache'
```

in my environment.rb

Answer (score 0):

Try to load it at the irb prompt.

```
# irb
> require 'rubygems'
> gem 'memcache-client'
```

This should give you a more descriptive error message.

Comment: Do you have require 'memcache-client' in environment.rb?

Comment: Thanks for your help, BTW. I do... the line looks like this:
config.gem "memcache-client", :lib => "memcache"

Comment: sorry, above that line i also have: require 'memcache'